# how do you filter data frame based on several columns in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame like this:

```
Server Avg_Cpu 95th 
Server01  40    90
Server01  45    90
Server02  56    80
Server02  50    80
```

I need to subset this data frame and pick the unique server that has the highest 95th and Avg_Cpu

my final df would be like this:

```
Server Avg_Cpu 95th 
Server01  45    90
Server02  56    80
```

I tried the dplyr package as follows:

```
df %>% group_by(Server) %>% filter(Avg_Cpu==max(Avg_Cpu))
```

Not quite working, getting:

```
Error: filter condition does not evaluate to a logical vector.
```

Comment: @bjosesph, I get this error: "Error: expecting a single value"

Comment: Please provide a `dput` of your data, otherwise we can't help you and this question will be soon closed.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `dput(df)` or `str(df)` to check the structure of your `data.frame`, `df`, because this works for me:

```
df <- read.table(textConnection("Server Avg_Cpu 95th 
                                 Server01  40    90
                                 Server01  45    90
                                 Server02  56    80
                                 Server02  50    80"), header = T)

library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(Server) %>%
  filter(Avg_Cpu == max(Avg_Cpu),
           X95th == max(X95th))

# Source: local data frame [2 x 3]
# Groups: Server [2]
# 
#     Server Avg_Cpu X95th
#     (fctr)   (int) (int)
# 1 Server01      45    90
# 2 Server02      56    80
```

Note in my case `str(df) returns:

```
# > str(df)
# 'data.frame': 4 obs. of  3 variables:
#   $ Server : Factor w/ 2 levels "Server01","Server02": 1 1 2 2
# $ Avg_Cpu: int  40 45 56 50
# $ X95th  : int  90 90 80 80
```

Comment: So You consider "*Your code works- here's a proof*" as answer? I think a proper comment should be "*Please provide a `dput` of your data*" first.